# Readonly property vs. readonly member variable in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class `ExProperty` something like below:

```cs
class ExProperty
{
    private int m_asimplevar;
    private readonly int _s=2;

    public ExProperty(int iTemp)
    {
        m_asimplevar = iTemp;  
    }

    public void Asimplemethod()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(m_asimplevar);
    }

    public int Property
    {
        get {return m_asimplevar ;}
        //since there is no set, this property is just made readonly.
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ap = new ExProperty(2);
        Console.WriteLine(ap.Property);
    }
}
```

1. What is the sole purpose of making/using a property readonly or write only? I see, through the following program that `readonly` achieves the same purpose!
2. When I make the property read-only, I think it should not be writable. When I use

   ```cs
   public void Asimplemethod()
   {
       _s=3; //Compiler reports as "Read only field cannot be used as assignment"
       System.Console.WriteLine(m_asimplevar);
   }
   ```

   Yes, this is ok.

   But, If i use

   ```cs
   public ExProperty(int iTemp)
   {
       _s = 3 ; //compiler reports no error. May be read-only does not apply to constructors functions ?
   }
   ```

   Why does the compiler report no error in this case ?
3. Is declaring `_s=3` ok? Or should I declare `_s` and assign its value using a constructor?

Comment: Oops! I was wrong in first question. "Readonly variables cannot be modified/written explicitly even by the methods of its class". Making a property readonly makes the varible readonly to other classes, however you can use/assign values to it using the methods of the class to which it belongs to!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `readonly` keyword means that the field can be written to only in a field initializer and in constructors.

If you want, you can combine `readonly` with the property approach. The `private` backing field for the property can be declared `readonly` while the property itself has only a getter. Then the backing field can be assigned to only in constructors (and in its possible field initializer).

Another thing you could consider is making a **`public`** `readonly` field. Since the field itself is read-only, you actually don't achieve much from the getter if all it does is returning the field value.

Comment: Thanks @Jeppe. But, what is the solepoint of using a property which is readonly or write-only when we can declare a variable itself as readonly ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: Because you might want to be able to modify the variable internally.

Comment: Thanks Mehrad. But, the third question is still unanswered ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. It's always fine to initialize the field when you declare it (called a field initializer), but of course in some cases you don't know its value already then. If you declare the field as `const` then you **have** to initialize it with the declaration, and it has to be initialized to a compile-time constant, and the `const` field cannot be assigned to, not even in constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Key point of properties is to provide interface for outside of the class. By not defining `Set` or by making it private, you make it "read-only" for outside of the class, but it can still be changed from inside of the class methods.

By making field `readonly`, you are saying it should never change, no matter from where this change comes.

Comment: If I had understood your answer correctly, the readonly variable cannot be modified even by the methods of the class to which it belongs to ? (But, in constructor however I can modify its value). Am I right in both cases ?

Comment: Yes. Readonly can only be set in constructor.